# Nativescript Angular TabView Scrollable

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, tabview

May I know how can I make the TabView Scrollable such that tab-names are not wrapped

`<TabView selectedIndex="1"  (selectedIndexChange)="onIndexChanged($event)" sdkExampleTitle sdkToggleNavButton>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab 1'}">
<tabone></tabone>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab 2'}">
<tabtwo></tabtwo>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab 3'}">
<tabthree></tabfree>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab 4'}">
<tabfour></tabfour>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab 5'}">
<tabfive></tabfive>
</StackLayout>
  </TabView>`

and it looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any NativeScript api that allows you to set the tabview as scrollable. so in the past, I've created a custom tab component using a ScrollView Horizontally.  here is a great example using the scroll view horizontally: http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/snippets/2016/05/30/horizontal-scroller.html. then show and hide different sections as depending on which button is tapped.

Comment: This is a great component! But it's not necessary to TabView using  nativescript-angular `~5.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript-angular `~5.2.0` provides it. Thank you NS!

Here you can prove the official-simple implementation:

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/cookbook/tab-view-ng

The `_automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` method is the responsible to do that.

https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_tab_view_.tabview

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I hope this helps!